# How to install maven on mac os and implement it in intellij IDE

Tags: java

I am only starting programming on Java and want to decided to create a simple Java Web Application. I've read that the maven and tomcat is needed(I've already installed tomcat), pls help me.

Comment: If you've just started programming, even a simple web application would be far from simple. You're going to have to do it like the rest of us: find tutorials, follow those, learn on the way. StackOverflow is for *specific* questions, so "help me" just doesn't fit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install homebrew (https://brew.sh/) then `brew maven`. But IntelliJ already comes with maven, so if you work only with IntelliJ, maybe you do not need to download maven at all. You can simply use maven that is bundled with IntelliJ..